# How to retrieve cookie value from HTTP_COOKIE variable

Tags: c, cookies, cgi

I am currently studying how to use cookies in my cgi program implemented using C language. I am having a difficult time acquiring the cookie I set.

From what I understand, environment variables such as HTTP_COOKIE, is my program's way of getting info from the server so I performed setting and getting of cookies as follows:

Setting:
I set a cookie from JS using document.cookie. I can see that this is set successfully because the cookie appears in my browser's debugger (I'm using firefox).

Getting:
I try to get the cookie value in my cgi program with getenv("HTTP_COOKIE") function. However, even if the cookie is already set, HTTP_COOKIE is still empty.

Am I missing to something in my procedure for setting cookies?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: are you sending the cookie to the server after setting in in the browser? try a refresh of the page in the browser

Comment: @bansi thank you for your reply. Yes I have tried refreshing the browser after setting the value of document.cookie. I was able to verify using fiddler that the Cookie parameter is indeed part of the HTTP request headers after refreshing the page. HTTP_COOKIE is still emtpy though when I try to retrieve it in my C code.

Comment: don't understand what you are doing wrong, but you should get the cookie in `getenv("HTTP_COOKIE")`